# using counter to get 2nd line on the files for multiple files in a folder

Tags: perl

I am trying to get all the 2nd line of each files from a folder. 
There is few files in the folder and i wish to get all the data in 2nd line and result in a single files. 
But my problem is when i run the script , i only get one data from a file. 
I cant get all the data from all the files. Need help on this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $first_line = 1;
my $last_line = 1;
my $file1; my $filename; my @file;
my $line; #read line
my $no_files=0; # total number of files
my $input_file; #input , output
my $directory = 'C:\Users\AAA';
my $count = 0;

opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR))
{
     if ($file =~ m/(sum\_)(\S+)\_(\S+)\_(\S+)\_\_(\d+)\_(\d+)\.txt$/)
    {
        $filename = "$directory\\$`$&"; # take text filename
            print "reading******** $filename\n";
            push (@file, "$filename") # save into array
    }
}


foreach $file1(@file)
{
    $input_file = $file1;
    open(INPUT, "$input_file") or die "$!";     # parse in txt file
    $no_files =$no_files + 1;
    print "foreach* $input_file\n";
    seek $input_file, 0, 0;
while ( <INPUT>)
{
  print "Beginning****** $input_file\n";
  print "$count\n";
  if ($count > $last_line)     # exit the program when you get to the last line
  {
    $count=0;
    close INPUT;
    exit;
  }

if ($count >= $first_line)  # print the current line if the line number is greater than our first param
{
print $_;
}
   $count++;  # increment the line counter
}

close INPUT;

} #foreach
```

**Input file example**
*File 1*

```
  Summary report
  12/05/2015 09:11:28
       Prog Name:    AAAF.xls
       Job Name:     FT_ROOM
       Lot:          U5AAAY_1A
```

**Input file example**
*File 2*

```
  Summary report
  12/05/2016 09:11:28
       Prog Name:    AAAF.xls
       Job Name:     FT_ROOM
       Lot:          U5AAAY_1A
```

**Input file example**
*File 3*

```
  Summary report
  12/05/2017 09:11:28
       Prog Name:    AAAF.xls
       Job Name:     FT_ROOM
       Lot:          U5AAAY_1A
```

**Output**

```
reading******** C:\Users\csleow\Desktop\P9038\FT_ROOM_sum_U59925MY_1A_K4B7501__12052015_042219.txt
reading******** C:\Users\csleow\Desktop\P9038\FT_ROOM_sum_U61853PY_2B_K4B7521__03112016_173308.txt
foreach* C:\Users\csleow\Desktop\P9038\FT_ROOM_sum_U59925MY_1A_K4B7501__12052015_042219.txt
Beginning****** C:\Users\csleow\Desktop\P9038\FT_ROOM_sum_U59925MY_1A_K4B7501__12052015_042219.txt
0
Beginning****** C:\Users\csleow\Desktop\P9038\FT_ROOM_sum_U59925MY_1A_K4B7501__12052015_042219.txt
1
12/05/2015 09:11:28
Beginning****** C:\Users\csleow\Desktop\P9038\FT_ROOM_sum_U59925MY_1A_K4B7501__12052015_042219.txt
2
```

**Output i would like to see :**

```
12/05/2015 09:11:28
12/05/2016 09:11:28
12/05/2017 09:11:28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

```
my $foldername = "folder";

foreach my $m (glob("$foldername/*"))
{
    open my $fh, "<", $m or die "$_ $!";
    <$fh>;
    my $second = <$fh>;
    ($fname) = $m=~m/\/(.+)/g;  
    print "$fname $second";
}
```

glob returns the list of files in a directory.

So the `foreach` Iterate for the each file in the folder.

After opening the file i continuously used the file handle. That the reason was you want the second line of the data in a file, so `<$fh>` will return the first line of the file. Then the second line of the content is stored into the `$second`. Then it will print

Comment: There is no need to put `$m` in double quotes as you don't need interpolation on a single variable. It's also a best practice to use `$fh` for file handles. In general, the problem OP has is not finding and opening the right files. You suggest `glob`, which is indeed an easier way, but the OP is really struggling with getting the second line. All that `seek` action going on in the question. You can improve your answer by _explaining_ why your code, and how.

Comment: @simbabque Thank you for your use full comment.  In after my every program i'll follow your tips :) .

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev Thank you. while editing makes mistake. Post edited. :)

Comment: Is it i need to use glob for this? Can i use back the one i am writing (counter) ? Cause i need to print out the filename and the 2nd line of the file together. If i use your code than i only able to get all the 2nd line of the files.

Comment: @Tree_Chee Simply extract the filename from `$m` using pattern matching. :) Post Edited

Answer (score -1):

Slightly adjusted example from mkHun:

```
my $foldername = shift @ARGV;

foreach my $filename (glob("$foldername/*"))
{
    if(  open my $handler, "<", $filename )
    {
        <$handler>;
        print scalar <$handler>;
        close $handler;
    }
    else
    {
        warn "Error opening $filename: $!";
    }
}
```

You are passing foldername as argument to a script and getting output to stdout.

Comment: When using lexical file handle no need to close it :).

Comment: yep, didn't know that :) anyway, just a habit

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev Hi Sir , want to ask you where should i put my directory path on the code? i see you pass argument to $foldername right?

Comment: @Tree_Chee you may pass it to the script, like ./myscript.pl dir_name or you may hardcode it instead of shift ARGV

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev Thanks Sir. I try and it works well. The Output i having was the 2nd line and ## Usable for P9038 [15March2016] . How come there is ## Usable for P9038 [15March2016] ?